# If two maps have the same dual map, do the two maps coincide?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces. And $L_1 : X \to Y$ and $L_2 : X \to Y$ be bounded linear maps. If the two maps have the same dual map, that is $L_1^*=L_2^*$, then is it possible to conclude that $L_1=L_2$? I cannot find a way to prove it, but am quite suspicious. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is a linear problem.  So it is the same as asking if $L^* = 0$ is $L = 0$?   If $L \ne 0$, then there is an $x \in X$ such that $Lx \ne 0$.  And since $Lx \ne 0$, there is (using Hahn Banach) a $\phi \in Y^*$ such that $\langle Lx, \phi\rangle \ne 0$.  Then $\langle x, L^* \phi\rangle \ne 0$, so $L^* \ne 0$.

Comment: I only assume normed spaces. But you used inner product.

Comment: No, I just wrote $\phi(Lx)$ as $\langle Lx, \phi \rangle$.  It's a common notational convention, but you can rewrite if you prefer.

Comment: $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ here refers to the duality pairing of a normed space with its dual. So for example if $\phi \in Y^\ast$ and $y \in Y$ then $\langle y, \phi \rangle := \phi(y)$.

Comment: Oh I see.... Ok

Comment: And nobody is correct in pointing out the existence of $\phi$ as claimed depends on Hahn Banach.  So the whole thing is  Hahn Banach corollary.

Answer (score 1):

As a corollary of the Hahn-Banach Theorem, for any distinct points $x,y \in Y$ there is a bounded functional $\phi_{x,y} \in Y^\ast$ such that $\phi_{x,y}(x) \neq \phi_{x,y}(y)$.

If $L_1 \neq L_2$ then there is a point $x \in X$ such that $L_1 x \neq L_2 x$. Then, by the above there is a $\phi \in Y^\ast$ such that $\phi(L_1 x) \neq \phi(L_2 x)$. Therefore $L_1^\ast \phi \neq L_2^\ast \phi$. This is the contrapositive of your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Of course this requires Hahn-Banach (or some other assumption beyond ZF) ... cannot be proved in ZF itself.

For nonzero Banach space $X = l^\infty/c_0$ it is consistent that $X^* = \{0\}$.  Then the zero and identity operators on $X$ both have the same dual.

Comment: Excellent way to totally confuse a beginner in functional analysis.